# Cannot read property 'ngbDateParserFormatter' of undefined Angular

Tags: angular, angular7

Iam converting a ngBootstrap date object to normal Date format using ngbDateParserFormatter, inside a custom validation function for a input field.

But on conversion its keeps getting error

> Cannot read property 'ngbDateParserFormatter' of undefined

I have used `ngbDateParserFormatter` on several places before in that file and its working fine.

My validation code:-

```js
export class ApplyLeaveComponent {
  constructor(
    private panelService: PanelService,
    private router: Router,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private ngbDateParserFormatter: NgbDateParserFormatter,
    private toastr: ToastrService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  applyLeave(data) {
    if (this.totalLeave - this.availedLeaves.length <= 0) {
      this.toastr.error("", "No Remaining Leaves", { positionClass: "toast- bottom-right" });
    } else {
      this.submitted = true;
      if (this.leaveForm.invalid) {
        return;
      } else {
        var leaveData = {
          financialYear: this.financialYear.id,
          profileId: this.userDetails.profileId,
          emailFrom: this.userDetails.email,
          leaveFromDate: this.ngbDateParserFormatter.format(data.value.leaveFromDate),
          leaveToDate: this.ngbDateParserFormatter.format(data.value.leaveToDate),
          leaveType: data.value.leaveType,
          leaveReason: data.value.leaveReason,
          notifyPerson: data.value.notifyPerson,
          reportingPerson: data.value.reportingPerson
        };
        this.applyLeaveService.SaveLeave(leaveData).subscribe(
          res => {
            console.log(res);
            this.leaveForm.reset();
            this.submitted = false;
            this.toastr.success("", "Leave applied Successfully", {
              positionClass: "toast-bottom-right"
            });
          },
          err => {
            console.log(err);
            this.toastr.error("", "Error on Applying", { positionClass: "toast-bottom-right" });
          }
        );
      }
    }
  }

  dateValidation(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {
    var currentvalue = control.value;
    console.log(currentvalue);
    var selectedDate = this.ngbDateParserFormatter.format(currentvalue);

    let dateFormat = require("dateformat");
    let now = new Date();
    var today = dateFormat(now, "dd mm yyyy");
    console.log(today);

    return null;
  }
}
```

[image: intellisence values on <code>this</code>]

`control.value` is a dateobject having value `{year: 2019, month: 6, day: 6}`

Can anyone solve?

Comment: `this` is undefined. it is a problem with function/class scopes. can you share more code especially the class you define `dateValidation` and the class you use it.

Comment: my validation function is correctly inside the class

Comment: `this` seems to be undefined, how do you call `applyLeave` or `dateValidation` when the error appear?

Comment: datevalidation function triggers only when i select a date from datepicker and that time error occurs.

also i can get `this` and its values inside validation function by intellisence automatically

Comment: i have updated a picture on question
please check

Comment: please share the code where/how do you use `dateValidation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea where exactly is `dateValidation` used in your code, but to fix that error, you will need to bind `this` onto your custom validator, `dateValidation`. This is because the context of the `dateValidation` method, when called by the Reactive Form `FormControl` is not referenced to your main `ApplyLeaveComponent`.

For instance, you can bind `this` to `dateValidation` by doing the following:

```
yourForm = this.fb.group({
  leaveFromDate: [null, [this.dateValidation.bind(this)]],
});
```

Comment: it worked well..
can u pls attach some related docs well to understand why my code didnt worked?

Comment: @AmeerPappay Hmm.. as i mentioned on my answer, thats because of the context of `this` is not referencing to your `ApplyLeaveComponent` class. You may read up more about `this` over here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)